# Tor mode activated in shell

Tags: command-line, tor

I recently added tor via this [site](https://linuxconfig.org/install-tor-proxy-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux), and ran torsocks through `$ echo ". torsocks on" >> ~/.bashrc`

Now each time I open terminal, I have a log of turning on/off tor:

[image: "Tor mode acitvated" log]

Is there any way to get rid of this? I don't personally need to run tor in the terminal, and each instance of a new terminal includes this history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, remove the new line you added from the file `~/.bashrc`. Here's a quick guide:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Type in `gedit ~/.bashrc`.
3. In the editor, look for the line that has `. torsocks on` on it.
4. Remove that line and save using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> or pressing the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.
5. Open a terminal and confirm it no longer shows up (you may also need to reboot the system).

Hope this helps.

Edit: After re-reading through that guide you linked, you may also need to run `source torsocks off` in a terminal.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped you. :)